# SOQL Query getting Notes and Attachments from Custom Object

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, attachment, notes

I am getting an error when executing the below query in the Developer Console:

```
select Id, Request_Title__c, 
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments where id='a3K8E0000000BIj'), 
(SELECT Id, Title FROM Note where parentid='a3K8E0000000BIj') 
from Request_for_System_Change__c where id='a3K8E0000000BIj'
```

When I just run this it works:

```
SELECT Id, Title FROM Note where parentid='a3K8E0000000BIj'
```

But when I try to include the Notes alongside the attachments in my main query for my VF page, I get this error message:

> ERROR at Row:3:Column:24
>   Didn't understand relationship 'Note' in FROM part of query call

So what's the correct way to include notes that have been added to a record in my Custom Object (**Request_for_System_Change__c**)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the correct Relationship Name (**Notes**). Also you don't need to check for parentId condition again in the inner query..

```
select Id, Request_Title__c, 
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments), 
(SELECT Id, Title FROM Notes) 
from Request_for_System_Change__c 
where id='a3K8E0000000BIj'
```