# Notes and Attachment Issues

Tags: soql, custom-object, attachment, notes

I have a Custom Object record that I went ahead and added an image attachment to and I also created a note related to that user.  I am having two problems:

1) I tried using [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105909/soql-query-getting-notes-and-attachments-from-custom-object) solution in the dev console `query editor, but I got  0 attachment results and 0 note results.

Specifically, here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  (SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments), 
  (SELECT Id, Title FROM Notes) 
FROM Student__c 
WHERE drupalId__c = 1
```

Why am I not receiving any results even though there clearly is an image and a note associated with this record

AND

2) When I look in the `Notes & Attachments` part in this record page, I see the image I uploaded, but I don't see the note.

Why does the note I created not appear in this list?

Comment: You are likely dealing with confusion over which kind of Note and Attachment (Classic vs. Lightning style) is involved. And it *is* quite confusing. I wrote an answer to a different [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248812/what-is-the-right-way-to-query-all-notes-attachments/248832#248832) that may be helpful.

Comment: I mean, would it really be a Salesforce feature if it wasn't nonintuitive and confusing?